# SQL Полнотекстовый поиск

Tags: полнотекстовый-поиск, sql-server-2008

Можно ли воспользоваться полнотекстовым поиском в ms sql server 2008 expres?

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Только нужно устанавливать не просто SQL Server 2008 Express, а [SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842). Если SQL Server 2008 Express у вас уже установлен, то сначала нужно его удалить.